# how make the crosshair move where the gun is pointing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a fps game with unity for android and i made the gun to rotate by the phone's gyroscope but the hit point and crosshair are still focused to the center of the screen . I want to make the crosshair to follow the direction of the gun. How is that possible?

Comment: I've never seen an FPS game where the crossair isn't centered in the screen. What do you mean by "follow the direction of the gun".

Comment: Do you have something that could be reviewed by the community?

Comment: If the crosshair follows the direction of the gun, what happens when the gun is facing the screen haha, crosshair is always the center of the screen and the camera is behind the player or basically in the head of the player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm sorry if my answer is under your knowledge, but I think this way would work.

You can use a RayCast going from the barrel to forward, get the hit point and convert it to screen coordinate... Then just move your crosshair to the bullet collision point converted in screen-coordinates.

You can find details of implementation for Raycast here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

and for WorldToScreenConvertion here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html

Comment: thank you i will try it and i will informe you if worked

Comment: You're welcome... I'll wait to know if worked

Comment: I think that i need more help. i did the think with the raycast, i draw a line to see in the scene if this is that i want and it is. But i need to change the projectile that the bullet use! the bullet still use the projectile of camera's raycast ! i use the ufps asset , in wιch script i have to make changes?

Comment: Well.. I dont have this asset, but I went to UnityAssetStore and could overview it, without accessing the codes and the models. Just the hierarchy.
What I could Find was... in the UFPS>Base>Content>Prefabs>ProjectilePrefab folder, I guess you can change the Texture and Mesh of the Projectile.
And in UFPS>Base>Scripts>Core>Editor, you can find a script named vp_FPWeaponShooterEditor.cs, which I guess you could find how it calls the prefabs.. Again.. its a guess.. I dont really know, cause I dont have the project in hands.. Try it.

Comment: Just one more thing.. if I could help you, you could choose my answer as the one which helped you.. I think you can't yet upvoted it, but you can turn the check to green and help me too haha.

Comment: thank you very much ! of course i can  help you as you did! i had found the prefab,  call it machingunbullet and there is a script  in it the vp_Bullet.cs that i think  control the projectile of the bullet. On the vp_FPWeaponshooter i made in the begging the change to rotate the rifle with gyroscope. Now i'm trying to copy the rotation values from vp_FPWeaponshooter(rifle) to vp_Bullet (projectile). Thank you again ! Sorry i'm a begginer!

Comment: Great that you found it! people aren't too patient here haha.. relax.. with time you get the way here..

Answer (score 0):

First sorry for my English!
Second I'm gone describe better that i want to do!
As i said in the beginning i made the rifle to rotate by the smartphone gyroscope! Because with the rifle rotation and the barrel of the rifle rotate , in the real world the bullet should goes to the different position every time that the user rotate the smartphone. even the rotation of player camera stays the same. So i want to make the bullet to go to the right position and the crosshair to move every time that the user rotate the rifle and pointing the right position that the bullet will go.